# Can a neural network predict with missing input values?

Tags: python, neural-network, missing-data

So I have been busy training a LSTM network and have found some information on training a network with missing values. However, this is while training. Can neural networks also predict when input values are missing? I've tried to set the missing values to the same value as missing inputs when training, setting it to 0, and setting it to np.NaN. There seems to be quite a difference between the missing training value and 0. Setting it to np.NaN also returns a NaN.

Is it generally a bad idea to try to predict when just one input is missing (out of 9)? Or are there other ways to incorporate this?

Comment: I would think that if value is missing, an appropriate value should still be given and this depends on the type of problem you are dealing with. Try checking this dicussion which proposes a few approaches: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_it_possible_to_train_a_neural_network_with_missing_data2